# Загрузка изображения в ImageView в фоновом потоке (файлы и url). Как узнать размер будущего изображения?

Tags: java, android, асинхронность, imageview, cursoradaper

Приложение - аналог чата. Имеется список (ListView). В нем элемент содержит текст и, возможно, картинку. Ну, как обычно бывает в месседжерах.

Для отображения элементов списка используется CursorAdapter. 
bindView просто создает ImageView, в AsyncTask происходит подгрузка и сохранение в память. В onPostExecute drawable оправляется в  ImageView.

Все замечательно, пользователь листает список, срабатывает bindView, но ImageView, когда создается, пуст и не отображается вообще. А после вставки картинки сдвигает список, и визуально это выглядит как подергивание интерфейса. Причем если листать список сверху вниз, то после прогрузки он сдвигает чат тоже вниз, и практически не заметно. А вот если листать чат вверх, то подгружаемые картинки толкают чат уже в другую сторону от скролла, короче эффект крайне неприятный для пользователя.

Да, можно вставлять какие-то служебные картинки до вставки нужной, типа "loading..."
Но тогда вопрос, как угадать с размером ? Сейчас использую картинку фиксированного размера 200, но подергивания видны все равно, хотя и исходные картинки близки по размеру.

Возможно неправильно использовать эту логику, подскажите что делать в данной ситуации?

Есть ещё предположение, что заставив систему делать bindView "как-то пораньше", было бы все проще, но в целом, это не решение проблемы.

Одно из решений, конечно же, установка фиксированной высоты изображения, но изображение может быть и вертикальным, и горизонтальным, так что это не особо выход.

Можно использовать сторонние библиотечки для фоновой загрузки, но решат ли они мою проблему со списком?

Код приводить особо смысла не вижу. 
Общая схема: view создается в UI, данные грузятся в фоне, данные вставляются в view. -> view растягивается непредсказуемо.

Comment: используете `Glide`/`Picasso` с `placeHolder`'ами?

Comment: @Jarvis_J
Нет, не использую, но упоминал это. Я не знаю какое изображение грузить в placeholder, ведь если я не угадаю с его размером, то лист также будет дергаться при вставке картинки. Или я не прав?

Comment: Glide/picasso Там на такие случаи есть дефолтная картинка и  метод resize т е все картинки автоматом будут сжиматься под одинаковый размер и ричего дергаться не будет

Comment: Нет, это не решение проблемы. Проблема все ещё актуальна. Размер картинок неизвестен заранее, дефортную картинку ставить некрасиво - если её размер сильно отличается, то исходная картинка сильно растянется\сожмется.

Comment: вам предложили хороший вариант, + посмотрите как это реализовано в viber, skype, whatsapp, или других. Получить размер картики вы можете всего двумя способами 1. послать запрос на сервер откуда загружаете эту картинку "дай мне размер такой то картинки" 2. Получить размер изображения только после загрузки самого изображения.
Вот заметьте как в скайпе это работает, вы скролите в самый верх после чего начинается загрузка предыдущих сообщений, после загрузки под них выделяется место, потом опять вы скрулите вверх и т.д. Может вам не достаточно функционала ListView...

Answer (score 0):

> Получить размер картики вы можете всего двумя способами. 1. послать запрос на сервер откуда загружаете эту картинку "дай мне размер такой то картинки" 2. Получить размер изображения только после загрузки самого изображения.

Да, согласен, и в моем случае я мог узнать размер только после загрузки.

> посмотрите как это реализовано в viber, skype, whatsapp, или других.

Имеется ввиду, наверное, связка RecyclerView + PagedListAdapter. Действительно, её функционал (прогрузка порции записей с сервера, когда список прокручивается к концу) мне нужен был, и я его добавил.

В целом, это помогает в моем случае. Так как с помощью этой связки либо картинки полностью загружаются в память к моменту показа, а значит их размер известен, и можно ставить соразмерный placeholder, либо view просто не отображается, пока не загрузится изображение. Причем, конечно, первый вариант должен срабатывать чаще, в чем и помогает PagedListAdapter.